# What is the period of a fuction which satisfies the condition $f(a-x)=f(a+x)$?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

What is the period of a function which satisfies the condition $f(a-x)=f(a+x)$ where a is any positive integer?

I tried substituting $x$ with $x-a$ but that does not seems to help me a lot.
I ended up getting $f(x)=f(-x+2a)$ I tried substituting other similar terms but was unable to get to a solution.

Comment: If $a$ is a particular number, then it does not have to be periodic at all. Consider $a = 0$ and $|x|$ as the function.

Comment: Can you please explain the point in detail with reference to the question? Isn't putting $a=0$ wrong as it is give $a>0$

Comment: In that case, I put $a = 1$ and use the function $|x - 1|$ so that $f(1 - x) = f(1 + x)$ and still it is not periodic. Same concept. I missed on your condition of $a$ being a positive integer. Can come up with many more examples -- but I think just one is enough to prove the point !

Comment: $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ has the property that $f(1-x)=f(1+x)$ but is not periodic.

Answer (score 1):

You need it true for $a=1,2$ to get periodicity.

Then $$f(2+x)=f(2-x)=f(1+(1-x))=f(1-(1-x))=f(x)$$

So you'd need to show that there is an example that has period $2$ and no smaller period to finish your proof. Try $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$.

If $S\subseteq Z$ and $f(a+x)=f(a-x)$ for all $a\in S,x\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ must have periodicity $2\gcd\{s_1-s_2\mid s_1,s_2\in S\}$, and you can find an $f$ with this exact periodicity.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are claiming in the last part of your answer. Surely the function given by 1 if rational and 0 if irrational does satisfy $f(a+x) = f(a-x) \, \forall  \, a \in \mathbb{Z} \, , \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Or even just the constant function. Are you assuming the period to be integral?

Comment: I didn't say "absolute" period. A function of period $n$ has period $2n$, etc.  The necessary and sufficient part is that given $S$, we can find a function which satisfies this with the GCD as the minimal period. I guess the words "at least" might be confusion, so I've removed them.